# How to get pages as a checkbox option in user profile

Tags: wordpress

i want to list the pages in checkbox in user profile for the users role to check specified page for them

```
function my_user_field( $user ) {

 $user_meta = get_the_author_meta( 'user_interests', $user->ID, true );?>


<table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th>


<label for="Dealing Type">Multi pages select for blurbs
        </label></th><td>
        <?php


$mypages = get_pages( array( 
                        'sort_column' => 'post_date', 
                        'sort_order' => 'desc' 
                    ) );


                if(count($mypages)){
                    foreach( $mypages as $page ) 
                    {   

                        $title = $page->post_title;
                        $slug = $page->post_name;
                        ?>
                        <label for='user_interests_<?php echo $page->post_name; ?>' class='blurb_user_label_checkbox'>
                              <input id='user_interests_<?php echo $page->post_name; ?>' name='user_interests[<?php echo $page->post_title; ?>]' type='checkbox' value='$page->post_title'
                               <?php if ( in_array( $page->post_title, $user_meta ) ) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?> class='blurb_user_checkbox'>
                              <?Php echo $title; ?>
                              </label>
                        <?php       
                    }
                }

                    var_dump($user_meta);

                ?>



        </td>

    </tr>


</table>
```

```
function my_save_custom_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
    return FALSE;

update_usermeta( $user_id, 'user_interests', $_POST['user_interests']);

}

add_action( 'user_new_form', 'my_user_field' );
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_user_field' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_user_field' );
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action('user_register', 'my_save_custom_user_profile_fields');
```

The checkbox is not working when options saved so please help me somebody. i hope guys you can help me.if there any other methods also please give me